PoseStamped Listener (python
Hey I am new to ROS2 and working in a large repository. I have created a node that listens to a topic that is of type PoseStamped. I created this listening node in python. However when I run it, it gives an error which I do not understand. Is there something that I am missing?
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

class PoseSubscriberNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("pose_subscriber")
        self.get_logger().info("Hello I am working")
        self.pose_subscription = self.create_subscription(
            PoseStamped, "/mocap/turtlebot/pose", self.listener_callback,10
            )       
        self.pose_subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info("I will get the Pose for you now")
        self.get_logger().info(msg.pose.position)
        

def main(args=None):
        rclpy.init(args=args)
        pose_subscriber = PoseSubscriberNode()
        rclpy.spin(pose_subscriber)
        pose_subscriber.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The indenation is not fully correct in this text box but it is in the file.
The error it gives is of the following type:
[INFO] [1711998839.108264885] [pose_subscriber]: Hello I am working
[INFO] [1711998839.813227729] [pose_subscriber]: I will get the Pose for you now
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tijmen/ros2_ws/install/tijmen_core_project/lib/tijmen_core_project/pose_subscriber.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/tijmen/ros2_ws/install/tijmen_core_project/lib/tijmen_core_project/pose_subscriber.py", line 24, in main
    rclpy.spin(pose_subscriber)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 222, in spin
    executor.spin_once()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 739, in spin_once
    self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 736, in _spin_once_impl
    raise handler.exception()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
    self._handler.send(None)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 437, in handler
    await call_coroutine(entity, arg)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 362, in _execute_subscription
    await await_or_execute(sub.callback, msg)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 107, in await_or_execute
    return callback(*args)
  File "/home/tijmen/ros2_ws/install/tijmen_core_project/lib/tijmen_core_project/pose_subscriber.py", line 18, in listener_callback
    self.get_logger().info(msg.pose.position)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/impl/rcutils_logger.py", line 329, in info
    return self.log(message, LoggingSeverity.INFO, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/impl/rcutils_logger.py", line 318, in log
    _rclpy.rclpy_logging_rcutils_log(
TypeError: rclpy_logging_rcutils_log(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int, arg1: str, arg2: str, arg3: str, arg4: str, arg5: int) -> None

Invoked with: <LoggingSeverity.INFO: 20>, 'pose_subscriber', geometry_msgs.msg.Point(x=-5.6917534846332944e-05, y=1.4944934235090915e-11, z=0.010007251957693237), 'listener_callback', '/home/tijmen/ros2_ws/install/tijmen_core_project/lib/tijmen_core_project/pose_subscriber.py', 18
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```


You are trying to log the position which is a message of type geometry_msgs/Point. This message contains the x, y and z coordinates of the pose you received. The self.get_logger().info() function takes in a string as an argument.
If you wanted to log the components of the position you could use an f-string like:
self.get_logger().info(f'x: {msg.pose.position.x}, y: {msg.pose.position.y}, z: {msg.pose.position.z}')

